# Webdriver check text box value before leaving this text box

Tags: java, webdriver, selenium-webdriver

I am using a generic method I created to type text in all my page objects.

Here is the code:

```
  public void clearAndSetValue(WebElement field, String text) {
        field.clear();
        field.click();
        field.sendKeys(Keys.chord(Keys.CONTROL, "a"), text);
  }
```

Now it comes to a need that I need to make sure that this method always check that the text box has been filled with argument text I pass to the method.

So I refine the method to be:

```
  public void clearAndSetValue(WebElement field, String text) {
    if (field.getText().equals("")) {
        field.clear();
        field.click();
        field.sendKeys(Keys.chord(Keys.CONTROL, "a"), text);
    }
  }
```

My intention is to make sure that the field value equal to whatever I want it to type, otherwise don't leave this method.

This method is not working as field.getText() always returns empty while there is string typed by the method inside the loop. I am guessing because getText() only return the field's original state?

This methods has been used by many other methods so I don't want to pass any more arguments to this method.

Is there a way to do this?

Thanks.

Comment: You should check both `getText()` and `getAttribute("value")`.

Answer (score 0):

What you need to do is, get the text of textbox after you do sendKeys and verify if it matches the input parameter(text), if it does then exit, else repeat the steps by using a loop logic. One thing you should be careful is that the loop does not go into infinite by having a flag to exit the loop.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I know I need to get the text after I sendKey, but how? Because as explained in the question, field.getText() returns empty after I sendKey.

Comment: getText() should work. Hard to tell without seeing the html for the element. As others have suggested you can try getAttribute or use JSExecutor also.

Comment: WebElement element = driver.findElement(By.id(""));
JavascriptExecutor executor = (JavascriptExecutor)driver;
value = executor.executeScript("return arguments[0].value;", element);

Answer (score 0):

You'll likely need to use `.getAttribute("value")` to capture the current text of the field.

So you method would likely look like this:

```
public void clearAndSetValue(WebElement field, String text) {
    if (field.getAttribute("value").equals("")) {
        field.clear();
        field.click();
        field.sendKeys(Keys.chord(Keys.CONTROL, "a"), text);
    }
}
```

NOTE: I'm guessing its going to be `.getAttribute()` as you've mentioned using a text-field element but without the HTML to look at I couldn't say for 100% certainty that it is.